# Unity3D: GetChild() vs FindGameObjectWithTag() vs attached prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was using GetChild() with the specific number as I arranged. But when the child objects started getting shuffling, I could not use GetChild().

Now I have three options.

```
1. Try to sort the child objects overtime they get shuffled. I need to
use this option when GetChild() is must faster compared to the
below.
2. FindGameObjectWithTag(): I read, Finding game objects with tags executes much faster than finding with names.
3. I have a total to 81 characters in the scene. Is it wise to attach all the 81 to the script upfront and access from that game
objects array?
```

Thanks.

Comment: The best way may lie in the reason why you are looking for that specific item. Is it a collision? Random? Based on name? Time? Anything?

Comment: Hi fafase,
There are 9x9 objects in the screen, And I ve kept a quad above all. when the quad is clicked, I take the hit point and by using the location, the object is selected. Objects will be named after their locations :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are instantiating all the 81 characters from single point, I see it perfectly valid to store them in collection for further operations or delegating the operation to different object for processing.

It's also true that searching with `tag` is one of the fastest way to search around, but as you are checking for `name`, not for `.GetComponent<T>()` it's circa the same time to find what you're looking for.
From programmatical side, I'd rather stick with collection and references than gameobject names, as name can easily change for any particular reason (for ex. somebody changes name of gameobject to type of characters).
Also, please note that gameobject name can be **duplicate**.

**Note:** you are referring to *attached prefabs* but you should actually store gameObjects that resulted from prefabs instantiation.

Comment: Hi mwilczynski,
I have decided to use collections. Could you rate between the three?
1. GetChild() ---
2. FindObjectsWithTag ---
3. Prefabs in Collections ---

:)

Comment: GetChild can have unintented behavior if name of GameObject changed, FindObjectsWithTag has about the same performance as instantiated prefabs collection, but only prefabs collection allow you to implement proper encapsulation.

Comment: What I mean is that if gameObject has tag attached, it is always globally public information.